# what is mean by apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev?

Tags: r

WHile i was trying to install "Devtools "packages in R.i was hitting with the following some errors like "Rcurl was not found " could not installed the packages .
After installing the following things ..it was worked perfectly 
**apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev**
**apt-get -y install libcurl4-gnutls-dev**

Can you guys explain me what is mean by above two lines.

Answer (score 1):

It's ubuntu/debian-ease:

```
apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

means install the build dependencies for `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

```
apt-get -y install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

means install the package `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

Presumably R needs these to work.